# Was Voldemort properly present during the MoM encounter after trying to possess Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

In the fifth instalment of the Harry Potter series, was Voldemort present as a being once finishing possessing Harry Potter? There is a brief period of time where Voldemort attempts to possess Harry Potter (which some may argue was successful), and my question revolves around the events after this. After taking over Harry's body, is Voldemort present as a normal being, with the abilities that come with that? For an example, is he able to use a wand? It would seem so as Cornelius and other Ministry officials spot him before leaving.

The reason I ask this is because I'd like to know if he had the ability to further attack Harry Potter whilst he was wandless and on the ground. Of course, he may have been pressed for time as the officials showed up, and as Dumbledore was actively present in the entire event. If he could further attack Harry Potter, why didn't he attempt to kill him? To my knowledge, he did not know of the blood that tethered Harry to life, so I see no reason in him not trying.

A video to further help you understand this scene can be found [here](https://youtu.be/TT9vPftessg?t=405).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### He certainly was.

From [this summary](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles%27_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Major_Events/Battle_at_the_Department_of_Mysteries) of the relevant part of the books:

> Suddenly, Dumbledore and Voldemort arrive, and duel each other, with Harry and Lestrange restrained by moving statues charmed out of the Fountain of Magical Brethren. Voldemort then tries to possess Harry, and flees when Harry's love for Sirius chases him out of Harry's mind. As **Voldemort returns physically to free Bellatrix**, Cornelius Fudge and a number of Aurors, summoned by Dumbledore, arrive and see him.

Re. your second paragraph, recall that Dumbledore was still present and able to fight Voldemort if he tried any sort of ordinary wand-attack on Harry. The only way Voldemort could think of to attack Harry without Dumbledore being able to defend him was to get inside his mind, into a place Dumbledore wouldn't be able to attack him. As @CandiedMango suggests, he may also have been exhausted and/or in pain from Harry's emotions, which had after all been powerful enough to *force* him out of possession.

If Voldemort had tried to attack Harry physically (rather than via possession) at that point, Dumbledore would presumably have defended Harry in exactly the same way as before, by duelling with Voldemort. And since he'd been unsuccessful in the first duel, and the Ministry officials were arriving to outnumber him, he accepted that "discretion is the better part of valour" and departed.

Comment: Excellent, and the second paragraph within my question? Do you have an answer regarding that as well?

Comment: @Jake Old Voldy was in pain from the emotions harry was feeling :)

Comment: This is a bit more complicated that Wikiblogs' summary.

Comment: I am more looking for an attack on this specific scenario. I.e, what would happen to Harry in this situation?

Comment: I was just asking what would happen if Voldemort attempted to kill Harry. It's up to you if you'd like to again edit your answer (my sincere apologies), however, I've awarded you the correct answer as you did answer the first part.

Comment: @Jake Thanks for the acceptance! :-) Re Voldemort attempting to kill Harry, have you seen [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99327/why-did-dumbledore-block-voldemorts-avada-kedavra-aimed-at-harry-potter) post? I'll try to edit my answer further tomorrow...

Comment: @Jake Sorry for the late response. I've just edited my answer to address the question of what would have happened. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 10):

***TL;DR:***

- He was not so much as **present**, as he **re-appeared momentarily to grab Bellatrix, as we can infer from MoM employee's statements**.
- However, **we do NOT see that reappearance in the narrative (including from Harry's POV)**.

---

***Details:***

On one hand, **he clearly disappeared from the hall before possessing Harry... AND didn't reappear later... AND the books explicitly says nobody was in the hall at that time**:

> For a few seconds Voldemort was visible only as a dark, rippling, faceless figure, shimmering and indistinct upon the plinth, clearly struggling to throw off the suffocating mass. *{{ This is the last moment he's visible - DVK }}*
>
> **Then he was gone and the water fell with a crash back into its pool, slopping wildly over the sides, drenching the polished floor**.
>
> 'MASTER!' screamed Bellatrix.
>
> **Sure it was over, sure Voldemort had decided to flee**, Harry made to run out from behind his statue guard, but Dumbledore bellowed: 'Stay where you are, Harry!'
>
> For the first time, Dumbledore sounded frightened. Harry could not see why: **the hall was quite empty but for themselves**, the sobbing Bellatrix still trapped under the witch statue, and the baby phoenix Fawkes croaking feebly on the floor

THEN, Harry gets possessed:

> Then Harry's scar burst open and he knew he was dead: it was pain beyond imagining, pain past endurance.
>
> ... *skip the paragraph's about Harry's attempted possession*
>
> And as Harry's heart filled with emotion, the creature's coils loosened, the pain was gone; Harry was lying face down on the floor, his glasses gone, shivering as though he lay upon ice, not wood . . .

AND THEN, Ministry people including Fudge **say that they saw Voldemort**. But when??? From previous quotes, he disappeared before they appeared! Contradiction!

> **And there were voices echoing through the hall**, more voices than there should have been . . . Harry opened his eyes, saw his glasses lying by the heel of the headless statue that had been guarding him, but which now lay flat on its back, cracked and immobile. He put them on and raised his head a little to find Dumbledore's crooked nose inches from his own.
>
> 'Are you all right, Harry?'
>
> 'Yes,' said Harry, shaking so violently he could not hold his head up properly. 'Yeah, I'm ... **where's Voldemort, where  who are all these**...  what's '
>
> **The Atrium was full of people**; the floor was reflecting the emerald green flames that had burst into life in all the fireplaces along one wall; and streams of witches and wizards were emerging from them. As Dumbledore pulled him back to his feet, Harry saw the tiny gold statues of the house-elf and the goblin, leading a stunned-looking Cornelius Fudge forward.
>
> '**He was there**!' shouted a scarlet-robed man with a ponytail, who was pointing at a pile of golden rubble on the other side of the hall, where Bellatrix had lain trapped only moments before. '**I saw him, Mr Fudge, I swear it was You-Know-Who, he grabbed a woman and Disapparated!**'
>
> 'I know, Williamson, **I know, I saw him too**!' gibbered Fudge, who was wearing pyjamas under his pinstriped cloak and was gasping as though he had just run miles. 'Merlin's beard  here  here!  in the Ministry of Magic!  great heavens above  it doesn't seem possible  my word  how can this be ?' *(HP: OoTP, Ch 36: The Only One He Ever Feared)*

The only explanation seems to be that **Voldemort re-appeared - not shown in the book's narrative, Harry-POV text - after possession, to grab Bellatrix, just as the Ministry employees arrived.**

Comment: Now the question is: what happens to V's physical body when he possesses somebody?